# The correct preposition: "Ich steige 'auf' /'in' die Buslinie ein."

Tags: preposition

What is the the correct preposition in this case? *Auf die* or *in die*?

> Ich steige *auf* / *in* die Buslinie ein.

Comment: Strictly speaking: neither. You can "in den Bus" or "in den Bus der Linie 42" (@Em1 maybe he meant that and your edit went into the wrong direction?) or "in den 42er (Bus)" einsteigen - but not "in die Buslinie". And of course not "auf".

Comment: @Matthias: Sounds like an answer to me - I had just contemplated to write one, but will step down  for you.

Comment: @Stephie Thank you. I will wait for a short while to see whether the OP accepts Em1's edit.

Comment: @Matthias Stimmt. Hatte beim Editieren nicht so direkt drüber nachgedacht. "Eine Buslinie nehmen" wäre aber natürlich in Ordnung.

Comment: @TheyCallMeLuke Note, that Matthias is right that you cannot say "in die Buslinie". You can only get on the bus, not on the 'bus route' / 'bus line'.

Comment: Buslinie is a general word for all busses on the same route so you can not interact directly with the Buslinie. You can only say that you want to use/travel on that route (with a bus driving this route): "Ich nehme die Buslinie 42."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely and only **in die**.

**Auf die Bahn steigen** would be maybe correct, if you think of people travelling on trains' roofs in India :)

Comment: "auf den Zug aufspringen" ;)

Comment: Ok, this one is an idiom :)

Comment: Except you can't really say »in die Buslinie einsteigen«. That sounds more like the bus line is a company and you're investing in it. See the other answer for possible ways to phrase this.

Answer (score 8):

The preposition you want to use is **in**. But you cannot use it together with *Buslinie* and *einsteigen*.

You can say

> in den Bus / in den Bus der Linie 42 / in den 42er (Bus) / in die 42 einsteigen

but not *in die Buslinie einsteigen*. Maybe you had "Bus der Linie X" in mind when writing you question, but it seems like you accepted @Em1's edit.

As @1Darco11 pointed out in the comments, *Buslinie* is a general word for all busses on the same route so you can not interact directly with a *Buslinie*. But you can say

> Ich nehme die Buslinie (or short: Linie) 42.

if you want to express that you want to take a bus of that line.

There are some vehicles where *auf* would be the right choice, like an open trailer (*Anhänger*), but then the verb to use would be *aufsteigen*.

Comment: In colloquial German, the name of the bus route may be used as a _totum pro parte:_ „vor mir fährt die Linie 42“ for „vor mir fährt ein Bus der Linie 42“ similar to „hinter mir fährt die Polizei“ for „hinter mir fährt ein Polizeiauto“

Comment: At least where I live (Nothern Bavaria) one could even say: *Ich steige in den 42er*, which summarizes a bus servicing line 42.