# Männliche und weibliche Zahlen (Schulnoten, Buslinien, ...)

Tags: gender, regional, numbers

Bekanntlich sind Schulnoten in Norddeutschland weiblich *(die Eins,
die Fünf),* in Bayern und Österreich dagegen männlich *(der Einser,
der Fünfer).* Wie ich [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20695/2786) entnehme, gibt es eine ähnliche Unterscheidung auch bei Buslinien: Für mich ist z. B.

> Ich sitze gerade in der 103 und steige am Rathaus in die 107 Richtung Bahnhof um.

idiomatisch, während man anderswo offenbar vom *103er* und *107er* (Bus)
spricht.

Ist der regionale Sprachgebrauch bei Buslinien, Schulnoten und ähnlichen Zahlen grundsätzlich einheitlich, oder gibt es Teile des deutschen Sprachraums, wo für Schulnoten und Buslinien *unterschiedliche* Genera gebraucht werden?

Comment: Die Noten in Bayern und Österreich haben sicherlich einen männlichen Artikel, weil dort das Wort Einser gebräuchlicher ist, als das Wort Eins. Dementsprechend wird auch der Artikel angepasst.

Comment: Ich war bisher immer der Meinung, dass sich das Geschlecht nach dem (ausgelassenen) Nomen richtet, also _der_ 10er = der Bus Nr. 10. Bei genauerem Nachdenken stelle ich aber fest, dass zB Straßenbahnen jdf in Wien genauso männlich sind, also _der_ 43er usw, wahrscheinlich von "Wagen" abgeleitet (vgl. _der_ D-Wagen). U-Bahnen und S-Bahnen sind jdf weiblich (die U3, die S1).

Comment: Grenze RLP/BW: Noten männlich wie "der Einser", Straßenbahnlinien weiblich wie "ich nehme die 5 nach Norden". Zu Buslinien kann ich nichts sagen, weil in meinem Dorf immer nur eine Buslinie verkehrte und ich es so kenne, dass die Busse nach dem Zielort unterschieden werden, wie in "ich fahr mit dem Landauer (Bus)".

Comment: @Ingmar, warum suchst Du nach einem Substantiv, dem Du das Geschlecht anlasten kannst, statt zu folgern, dass es immer "die Sechs" und "der Sechser" ist, egal was es bezeichnet?

Comment: In Linz sagt man m. W. _die_ 1er, die 2er und die 3er (Straßenbahn); auch dort bekommt man in der Schule aber einen Einser und fährt mit _dem_ 12er (Bus).

Comment: Für mich ist beides gleichermaßen richtig: "in die 103" und "in den 103er". Es ist nur nicht gängig hier "103er" zu sagen. Aber würde ich es tun, wäre es automatisch männlich. Genauso wie man ja "einen 6er" im Lotto haben kann. Hat nix damit zu tun, dass die Linie 103 sonst für mich weiblich ist.

Comment: @Chris Da Baden und die Pfalz Übergangsgebiete sind, wo bei Schulnoten beide Genera gebräuchlich sind (http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f10a-b/), sind dort tatsächlich Abweichungen am ehesten zu erwarten.

Comment: "Die Eins" bezeichnet die abstrakte Zahl bzw. Ziffer an sich, während die flektierten Formen für "konkretes" (Sechserpack zB) gebraucht werden. Es gibt weder eine 49-Linie noch ein Sechspack. Eine "Sechs" im Lotto bedeutet nicht unbedingt einen Gewinn. Auf Busse (fahre immer mit *der Neun* nach Hause) etwa lässt es sich dennoch übertragen, da es sich idF um einzelne Objekte handelt. Aus diesem Grund kann man in der Schule sowohl eine Vier als auch einen Einser bekommen.

Comment: Ich habe in Köln wenn möglich "den 130er" genommen (von "der Bus") genommen, um von Sülz nach Rodenkirchen zu kommen, aber nachts und am Wochenende fuhren nur "die 16" und "die 18" (von "die Straßenbahn"). In der Schule hatte ich je nach Tagesform "das Fünfli", "den Einser" oder auch mal "eine Drei" gehabt.

Answer (score 2):

Hier haben nicht die Zahlen ein Geschlecht, sondern das weggefallene Objekt.
Ergänzt würde der Satz oben lauten:
Ich sitze gerade in der (Bahn/Linie) 103 und steige am Rathaus in die (Bahn/Linie) 107 Richtung Bahnhof um.
Für Busse geht alternativ auch "in dem 103".

Comment: In den Kommentaren wurden bisher drei Varianten erwähnt:
Bei "in der 103" und "in der 103er"
könnte man "Linie" oder "Bahn" ergänzen,
bei "im 103er "Bus" oder "Wagen".
Aber von "im 103" höre ich zum ersten Mal.
Wo ist denn das für Busse gebräuchlich?

Comment: Kenne die Verwendung aus dem Ruhrgebiet und hab sie schon im Münsterland gehört.